# Accessing terms in TDM

Tags: r, dataframe, tm

I need to access each individual Term in the unigram I have created. However it is the 0th column and I don't know how to access. This is slightly stupid question I presume

```
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(docs)
a <- as.matrix(tdm)
unigram <- as.data.frame(a)
colnames(unigram) <- c("freq")
```

How can I access the fact that "sam" is 2 in this data frame as this is the 0th row.  I would like to do 2 things. a) Name the 0th column. b) Search the 0th column for the word for e.g "not". and get the value of "freq". If this was the 2nd or 3rd column it would have been easy

```
 > unigram
         freq
  and      1
  eggs     1
  green    1
  ham      1
  like     1
  not      1
  sam      2
```

Help.

Regards
Ganesh
not      1
sam      2

Comment: I'm not clear on what you want to do here. Are you trying to figure out how to look up freq in unigram for a specific term? In other words, what is the output you want?

Comment: @ulfelder - I want to do 2 things. a) Name the 0th column. b) Search the 0th column for the word for e.g "not". If this was the 2nd or 3rd column it would have been easy

Comment: by 0th column, do you mean `rownames(unigram)` ? in that case `unigram$freq[rownames(unigram) == "not"]`

Comment: @scoa - Thx. That is precisely what I was searching for! If you answer this , I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 0th column you are looking for seems to be the row names of the data frame. To find the freq for a given value :

```
unigram$freq[rownames(unigram) == "not"]
```

You could also make it a variable so it's easier to use

```
unigram$term <- rownames(unigram)
unigram$freq[unigram$term == "not"]
```

Comment: Thx a million. You read my mind!

Comment: If you're repeatedly going to look up values for specific terms, why not make a function to do that: `lookup <- function(term)  {unigram$freq[unigram$term==term] }`? Then, e.g., `lookup("not")`.

Comment: @ufelder. Perfect. You did it too!(read my mind).  Thx!

Answer (score 0):

You could use inspect function as part of the TM package.  You could create a vector of words you are interested in and then apply inspect to see only those words and their frequencies like the following:

```
my.filter.words <- c('sam','not')
inspect(tdm[my.filter.words,])
```